# TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function (Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to use the update feature from the cloud firestore to subtract from the original field with a inputed values but my function isn't working well . Here's the code .

```
const postID = document.getElementsByClassName("newID")
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

  buttonpay.addEventListener("click", handleUpdate);

  async function handleUpdate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get form input values
    const description = document.getElementsByClassName("description").parseInt - document.getElementsByClassName("quantity-input").parseInt
    try {
      const docRef = doc(db, "posts", postID);
      await updateDoc(docRef, {
        description,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
});
```

i've tried searching for the solution but none worked . can someone fixed it ?

Comment: Is it throwing the error that is in the title?

Comment: This usually means that you're passing a variable without a value to a Firestore call. In your case, the most likely one is `postID` in `doc(db, "posts", postID)`. To verify this: `console.log(postID)` on the line above it, or wrap the entire block in an `if (postID) { ... }` guard.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the error is when you use `getElementsByClassName`. meaning as this method returns collection of elements you should access them individually.
And I am doing it assuming you have only single element with that class name.

```
const postID = document.getElementsByClassName("newID")[0]; // Assuming there's only one element with the class "newID"
const buttonpay = document.getElementById("buttonpay"); // Assuming you have an element with the id "buttonpay"

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  buttonpay.addEventListener("click", handleUpdate);

  async function handleUpdate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get form input values and convert them to integers
    const descriptionValue = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("description")[0].value); // use [0] to access the element.
    const quantityValue = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("quantity-input")[0].value);

    // Subtract quantity from description
    const description = descriptionValue - quantityValue;

    try {
      const docRef = doc(db, "posts", postID.value);
      await updateDoc(docRef, {
        description: description,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
});
```